# How to make waveform with external audio link in React/NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, audio, wavesurfer.js

I've used wavesurfer.js and react-audio-visualize.

But if I try to fetch the audio using axios so I can convert it to BLOB, it gives me a network error.

And if I try put the url in wavesurfer.js instance, it also returns Network Error.

I want to get audio files from the database and render a player on the frontend and also show a waveform for each of them.

Currently, the dummy link I'm using, ReactHowler can play the audio from that link but strangely I can't fetch it nor use it in waveform.

I even went to wavesurfer.js example playground and used the link there and it doesn't there either.

I may be going in a completely wrong direction but thanks for your help.

https://samplelib.com/sample-mp3.html

Audio links are from there.

Tried to fetch audio using axios and fetch API. Failed. Tried wavesurfer. Failed to fetch. I know the cors error but I'm getting it on each direct audio link I try.

Comment: It seems that the CORS was issue all along. I used replicate audio and it worked fine.